# Gmail's mails on Apple mail app keep going to archive and not going through rules

Tags: macos, iphone, mail.app, email, gmail

So, I am currently running MacOS Ventura Public beta and I don't know if this is because I'm running the public beta, but most of my emails that I receive on my gmail account gets moved to archive automatically on my apple mail app. And this leads to the rules that I have setup not running properly and I get an error message like this, I am confused as to why this is happening.

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHJxU.png)

[image]

That is how I setup my rule for Potential Junk mails. If anyone can help me figure this out, that'd be really helpful. I don't get these error messages on my iPhone but I don't see any of my rules running on the iPhone mail app either (Running IOS 16 public beta).

Comment: Rules in the macOS Mail.app don't run in the iPhone Mail.app.

Comment: Google's implementation of IMAP is more than vanilla. I long ago gave up on rules in the Mail app - much more reliable to put them on the Google server (via the web interface). You also should consider which folders (or pseudo folders) you want synchronised between Google and Apple Mail (I don't sync Archive) - look in the Google IMAP settings via the web interface.